# Yum throwing dependency error even when the package is available

Tags: php, yum, rpm-spec

I've downloaded some older php packages from Webtatic which are required for my application and created a local repository (repo_php). One of the packages in my 'repo_app' has a dependency on packages from repo_php. While installing, yum returns the following error.

```
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: app-platform-20190921-6.el7.centos.x86_64 (repo_app)
           Requires: php72w-mbstring >= 7.2.16-1
           Available: php72w-mbstring-7.2.16-1.w7.x86_64 (repo_php)
               php72w-mbstring = 7.2.16-1.w7
Error: Package: app-platform-20190921-6.el7.centos.x86_64 (repo_app)
           Requires: php72w-ldap >= 7.2.16-1
           Available: php72w-ldap-7.2.16-1.w7.x86_64 (repo_php)
               php72w-ldap = 7.2.16-1.w7
...
...
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The `app-platform-20190921-6.el7.centos.x86_64` is an application package which requires the php packages to be installed from repo_php. From the error log it can be seen that the required package is available but still Yum is unable to proceed with the installation. I've tried using different php version naming in  the Requires tag of app-platform rpmspec file. Running out of options to troubleshoot.